# Use dumpbin to show External symbol(UNDEF) for DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, dumpbin

We all know we could use dumpbin for .obj file to show all the symbols including external ones.

```
dumpbin /symbols ExternCTest.ob
00F 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?foo@@YAHH@Z (int __cdecl foo(int))
```

But I am wondering how could I do this for DLL ? 
I have also tried dumpbin /exports as well as dependency walker but it's **NOT** showing external symbols.

How should I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: /exports shows you what the DLL exports.  /Imports shows you what external dependencies the DLL has, symbols that it needs to resolve by loading other DLLs.  The equivalent of your snippet.  If you get no output from /exports then you forgot to export functions with `__declspec(dllexport)`

Comment: Thanks! is it doable from dependency walker for showing external symbol? I am trying to do analysis on a PC doesn't have Visual studio installed which probably mean dumpbin might not work ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Go to a separately standalone PC trying to check which component is out of date/sync as it's trying to access a external link that doesn't exist anymore. I can run Dependency walker there, probably not dumpbin?

Comment: Clearly you care about /imports here.  Maybe you can diagnose it with depends.exe, it depends.  It could be a dynamically loaded DLL or a COM component.  You'll need to use its Profile option to see those.  SysInternals' ProcMon utility shows everything.

Comment: Looks like DW does the job but how does ProcMon do the trick ? I normally use it for file/reg monitoring...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command line argument you are looking for is `/imports`. This will show all external symbols referenced by the DLL.

Comment: Thanks! is it doable from dependency walker for showing external symbol? I am trying to do analysis on a PC doesn't have Visual studio installed which probably mean dumpbin might not work ?

Comment: Yes, Dependency Walker will show both imports and exports for a PE file. It should also work just fine without VS installed (it's available as a separate app).